# Decommission Tridion

Tags: 2011, 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion

What will happen once we decommission Tridion or don't renew SDL contract?
Sites currently working on Tridion will still work?
All the published content will be in database, does that mean current site will continue working as is, but we cannot update any content after that?
What will happen to CM and CD database, once we decommission Tridion?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Editing for clarity.**

<s>If by decommission you mean "stop paying the support fees, but keep the software running",</s>

Assuming what you intend to do is to continue using the software but stop paying the support & maintenance fee, that's exactly what will happen. Your current version will continue running, and everything will work as is, but:

- you won't be eligible for updates, upgrades or hotfixes (actually not 100% sure on hotfixes, as they could potentially include security fixes - I would ask support to be sure)
- you won't be entitled to open incidents with support

Normally the on-premise licenses for Tridion are "perpetual", you have the right to run the software forever (there are exceptions to this, not all licenses are the same, and you should check your contract).

Comment: thanks! Will I be able to update the content after decommissioning ?

Comment: For clarity: "decommissioning" means "taking out of service".  I don't think that's what you want to do. You just want to stop your support contract and keep using the software.

Comment: Is there a cost associated to keep using the software? Does that mean cost to support contract and software are different?

Comment: @nuno, irc if licenses expire we get an error logging into the cme and if CD expire, the publishing and website errors (circa tridion 2013 and possibly 8.5).

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov licenses for partners or developers are normally time-based, they will expire after a year or so. Customers tend to get licenses based on machine names, which won't expire.

Comment: Which, as Quirijn notes - adds another risk - you're tied to the same machines as you won't be able to use the licenses elsewhere.

Comment: The license files are not the license. You really need a lawyer to look at your contract. Even if you have 'perpetual' license files, that doesn't guarantee you have the right to use the software without a contract. That said, I have personal experience of SDL being very supportive of a customer who was leaving; they did everything to assure a soft landing.